# Windows 2008 R2 Print Server. Copying printer and giving new driver

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printer, print-server

Is there a way of copying a printer on a print server (Server 2008 R2) and then giving it a new name and new print driver?
In a nutshell - 1 printer but with two names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily.

You create a new printer with the new name and driver. Then assign it to the same printer port as the existing printer.  You may also specify different drivers (PS, PCL5 PCL-XL) as well as set queue-specific defaults for each instance, *e.g.* Color/BW, duplex, etc.

This is the "printer" view in `printmanagement.msc` for two printers on the same port with different drivers.

[image]

And here's what the "ports" view looks like. Note there are three printers on the one port.

[image]